# python geopy get city and country

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to get city and country names with geopy.

Normally this is how you can get city and country using geopy.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=3)
geolocator.reverse('52.5094982,13.3765983')
loc = location.raw
loc_dict = location.raw
print(loc_dict['address'])
```

and this is the output:

```
{'suburb': 'Tiergarten', 'country_code': 'de', 'country': 'Deutschland', 'postcode': '10117', 'attraction': 'Potsdamer Platz', 'road': 'Potsdamer Platz', 'city': 'Berlin', 'city_district': 'Mitte', 'state': 'Berlin'}
```

My problem is that geopy returns city and country names in their country language, for example:

```
city: Berlin, country: Deutschland
city: København, country: Danmark
city: București, country: România
```

i want them like this:

```
city: Berlin, country: Germany
city: Copenhagen, country: Denmark
city: Bucharest, country: Romania
```

Is it possible to get them in english as i want? or convert them somehow? I am using all countries and cities arround the world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

adding language in `reverse()` function should solve your problem:

```
geolocator.reverse(location, language='en')
```